# Wrapping NodeJS's net.createServer into a producer of customised sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, stream

I'm trying to make a function which behaves like `net.createServer`, except that it returns objects which are wrappers around sockets, instead of sockets.

(The point of these will be to do automatic data conversion.)

My latest attempt looks like:

```
var net = require('net');
var util = require('util');
var stream = require('stream');
var EventEmitter = process.EventEmitter;

exports.createServer = createServer;

function createServer(arg0, arg1) {
  var server;
  var netServer;
  var ocb;

  if (typeof arg1 === 'function') {
    // options, callback
    netServer = net.createServer(arg0, callback);
    ocb = arg1;
  } else if (typeof arg0 === 'function') {
    // callback
    netServer = net.createServer(callback);
    ocb = arg0;
  } else {
    // options?
    netServer = net.createServer(arg0);
    ocb = null;
  }

  server = new Server(netServer);

  function callback(socket) {
    ocb(new LiftedSocket(socket));
  };

  return server;
  ;
}

function Server(netServer) {
  this.netServer = netServer;
}
util.inherits(Server, EventEmitter);

Server.prototype.listen = function() {
  this.netServer.listen.apply(this.netServer, arguments);
}

function LiftedSocket(socket) {
  stream.Duplex(this);
  this.socket = socket;
}
util.inherits(LiftedSocket, stream.Duplex);

LiftedSocket.prototype._read = function(size) {
  console.log('_read', size);
  // transforming code goes here
  this.socket.read(size);
}
LiftedSocket.prototype._write = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
  console.log('_write', chunk, encoding, callback);
  // transforming code goes here
  this.socket.write(chunk, callback);
}
```

But when tested (by trying to pipe from a returned `LiftedSocket`) it fails with errors including:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipesCount' of undefined
  at LiftedSocket.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:453:16)

 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'flowing' of undefined
  at LiftedSocket.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:691:44)
```

I expect I'm doing something wrong when constructing the `LiftedSocket`, but I can't think what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had called the superclass constructor incorrectly.  It should have been:

```
stream.Duplex.call(this, {})
```